# Web API and Angular 5 Token Authentication - Get user info after log in

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, token

When i access my angular app, i get this:

```
access_token:"******************"
expires_in:59
refresh_token:"******************"
token_type:"bearer"
```

But now I would like to use the information of the user who logged in. My problem is that I can not because I do not have the user id between the token information.

This is my c# login from API:

```
//Varifying user credentials
    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceContext db = new ServiceContext();
            var userInfo = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userInfo != null)
            {
                string stringPwd = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(userInfo.Password);
                return stringPwd == password;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my Authentication Service from Angular App:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

login(username: string, password: string) {

    var data = "grant_type=password" + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/token`, data, { headers: reqHeader })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.access_token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
            return user;
        }));
}
```

This is my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        Accounts acc = new Accounts();

        //Authenticate the user credentials
        if (acc.Login(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, acc.GetUserRole(context.UserName)));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
```

I would like to display the username used for login. Can someone help me and give me some advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to pass username with your token data in your `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method

Comment: i have post my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials. There is username info, but how i use on angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method like below

You need to use `AuthenticationProperties` that you can add more parameters with your token data.

And `AuthenticationTicket` will bind your added parameters to your token data and your will access those data in your angular app.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    Accounts acc = new Accounts();

    //Authenticate the user credentials
    if (acc.Login(context.UserName, context.Password))
    {   
        //If you want to display user's firstname, lastname, or picture then
        //The below method is for getting user from database by its username
        var user = acc.GetUserByUsername(context.UserName);
        string firstName = user.FirstName;
        string lastName = user.LastName;

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, acc.GetUserRole(context.UserName)));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {                             
                         {
                             "userName", context.UserName
                         },
                         {
                             "firstName", firstName
                         },
                         {
                             "lastName", lastName
                         }
                    });

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
    else
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
        return;
    }
}
```

And add this method to below of `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

**Output:**

```
access_token:"******************"
expires_in:59
refresh_token:"******************"
token_type:"bearer",
firstName: "Abc",
lastName: "Pqr",
userName: "Xyz"
```

Comment: @Tky17, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: I tryed your solution, but my token info are always the same..without the user info (i copy and past the code that you have post and add GetUserByUsername funcion on my accounts Class).

Comment: try to add breakpoint in same method and watch `var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);` properties. are u getting `props` inside it? or copy here your `props` values

Comment: try to call your `/token` url with posted data in Postman and let me know what you will get. I'll be back within an hour :)

Comment: I tryed with postman and my result:
"access_token": "**",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 59,
"refresh_token": "**"

But with breakpoint, ticket has the user info

Comment: I added `TokenEndpoint` method in my answer. you just copy it and paste in your code just below of `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` and try once with Postman and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Usually `login` action should be followed by `/me` request, which reads the token from headers and returns the user object. 
Login/Register routes should only return token data, that is correct, but `/me` will be decoding token(in case you have included user data in token), or it will search for a user by his/her token in database.